# Exception is not being caught when program installed with a msi file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I made a WPF program that works in the VIsual studio when run. 
I made an installer for my program with Visual Installer Projects 2017. At one part the program crashes and I get the following dialog:

> An unhandled Microsoft.NET Framework exception occured in Program1.exe [10204].

My catch block looks like this

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                EnableContent();
            }));
        }
        catch (AggregateException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                UpdateLoadMsg("No internet connection.", MsgType.FAIL);
            }));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                UpdateLoadMsg("Something went wrong.", MsgType.FAIL);
            }));
        }
```

Messagebox is never showed! apparently the exception isn't being catched. How to debug this?

Comment: Do you have the exception data that was dumped in your PC that it was installed on?

Comment: @vipersassassin where can I find the exception data on my pc?

Comment: There should be something in the system event log.  But are you *sure* that the exception is originating from inside that `try` block?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Hello thank you I found the logs and apparently a FileNotFoundException is being thrown. I dont know why this is happening as the file that is being looked for is I checked "Build action=embedded resource"

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to access the resource?

Comment: I solved the problem! Apparently build action = embedded resource isnt enough. What I did was just adding the file to the installation folder of the program.

Comment: Yes, Embedding the file as a resource doesn't actually place the file in the filesystem, in fact, it does the exact opposite.  What it actually does is literally embed the file inside the executable.  You need to access the file a different way to use it from a  resource.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142927/discussion-between-nahro-and-bradley-uffner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Relevant

I found the causing exception by looking at the system logs http://www.dummies.com/computers/operating-systems/windows-10/how-to-use-event-viewer-in-windows-10/ .

### Non-relevant

The exception that was being thrown was a FileNotFoundException. Setting buildaction = embedded resource wasn't enough, I had to add the file as additional installation file.